# How do I update schema with DBIC make_schema_at?

Tags: mysql, perl, schema, dbix-class

I am currently using the DBIC Schema Loader function make_schema_at to dump my existing database into its schema. Once the schema is dumped I generally like to go in and clean up the accessor names in the relationships to read better.

However from time to time I need to update my schema again, for example adding in a new table and relationship which means calling make_schema_at again and then renaming all of my accessors which is very time consuming.

Is there a better approach to this that anyone can recommend?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple solutions for this.

Either use the configuration options of Schema::Loader to specify subs for name generation and/or make your DBIC schema the master.

In this case you write a new result class instead of creating the table in your database and use DBIC's feature to generate the DDL queries.

You can even use DBIx::Class::Migration to automate the DDL changes to your databases.

Comment: Thanks abraxxa, I tried changing the naming method to v8 but that didn't suit my needs. I'm not sure how to go about creating a custom naming sub, could you point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

Never edit the code above the MD5 hash in a generated DBIC schema file. you'er just making trouble for yourself.

It's well worth taking the time to read the documentation for [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader%3a%3aBase). In particular, take a close look at the "moniker_map", "col_accessor_map" and "rel_name_map" attributes.